# Is it possible to detect two seperate swipes? (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, swipe

I try to make a simple but unusual 2D game for android using Unity in which player is supposed to move two different objects in two different halfes of the screen(heah that sounds stupid, sorry) AT THE SAME TIME. So, most of the work is done but I found a problem I've no idea how to deal with - I can't swipe in both halfs of the screen at the same time. If I want to move both objects in both halfs of the screen AT THE SAME TIME I won't be able to do it. It is so because my script for swipes checks position of first touch and then waits for an end of swipe. So if I touch both halfes of the screen and than make a swipe by stopping touching the screen the script will only detect the swipe in the half I first touched the screen.
Sorry for bad description. :(
Any thoughts?

Comment: Related: [How to implement multitouch in Unity3d on mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30847057/295004) but you should edit your post to include code as to how you are doing detection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious variant (in case I understood your problem correctly) is to change your input code to be able to work with several touches, not single. It should work like this:

- detect new touch (check if the `Input.touchCount` is greater than the number of currently tracked touches)
- store info about handled touch (you can use `fingerId` value from `Touch` structure)
- find an object, that will be affected by this touch (it seems like you already have this functionality)
- listen to ALL updates for ALL touches to affect corresponding objects if it is needed.
- remove handled touch on finger release from tracked touches

So you should work with ALL touches, not just the first one. Also, make sure that you have `Input.multiTouchEnabled` set to true.